# laravel foreach and if else loop errors both in count and variables something

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vs-web-site-project

code of 1st error :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h1> posts</h1>
@if(count($posts)>1)

@foreach($posts as $post)

<div class="well">
    <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
</div>
@endforeach

@else
<p> no posts found</p>
@endif
@endsection
```

and image also attached .
[enter image description here][1]
after i follow the instructions of the chrome this occurs and code will be .. even i have removed the @ and try if() like this ..
code 2 ;
 @extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<h1> posts</h1>
@if(count($posts ?? '')>1)

@foreach($posts ?? '' as $post)

<div class="well">
    <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
</div>
@endforeach

@else
<p> no posts found</p>
@endif
@endsection
```

Error images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/21weC.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDdF2.png

Comment: If `$posts` is not set `count($posts ?? '')` defaults it to `''` which isn't countable, try `$posts ?? []` which defaults it to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter approach for this would be:

```
@forelse($posts as $post)

<div class="well">
    <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
</div>

@empty

<p> no posts found</p>

@endforelse
```

You can find more loops available in the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops

Answer (score 0):

Use forelse instead of foreach, that should do the job